# Authenticating user from SSO + OpenID in django for google apps custom domain

Tags: python, django, oauth, google-apps, google-openid

After a lot of reading and researching i found the following [library](https://github.com/simul14/django-googleappsauth), the most suited to work for my needs: to signup/login a user using a custom google apps domain.

I did the following settings:

```
GOOGLE_APPS_DOMAIN = 'example.com'
GOOGLE_APPS_CONSUMER_KEY = 'example.com'
GOOGLE_APPS_CONSUMER_SECRET = '*sekret*'
# domain where your application is running
GOOGLE_OPENID_REALM = 'http://*.hudora.biz/'
    GOOGLE_OPENID_ENDPOINT = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud'
```

added custom middlewares and other stuff.

But from now, where do i take it further, showing a form and making form posts to urls, how do i ask user information, it is not given in the docs.

- Can anybody please help me with it?
- How do i give a user the functionality to login/signup?
- How do i customize a view?

Comment: I think the library you are trying to use may not be a great fit for you: https://github.com/simul14/django-googleappsauth/blob/master/requirements.txt#L2. It was made for django version: 1.0.2-final, we are in 1.4.x now. also it was last supported 9 months ago (and you linked a fork not the original: https://github.com/hudora/django-googleappsauth, was that on purpose?)

Comment: i found this one to have more commits. using the answer i got below things seem to have working. what changes in case if any should i make. in case someone is ready to tell me what do i need to do to upgrade this library, probably i will fork it and do as directed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. For the sake of testing it on your localhost following are things you need to do:

1. You need to register an app at the [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/) (while registering, put your domain 127.0.0.1:8000 or the exact location where your server is running)
2. You need to check the scope for your project, eg. calendar or maps etc.
3. You need to get the secret key.
4. Once you have got the secret, put them in your settings file, as described above. Change example.com and *.hudora.biz to 127.0.0.1:8000
5. Import the views from the [library views](https://github.com/simul14/django-googleappsauth/blob/master/googleappsauth/views.py) for login and logout and map them to your urls probably login/logout.

This is all that is reqd. Hope it helps!